# Improve PostgreSQL SELECT performance in a parent table (inheritance)

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance, inheritance

I have a PostgreSQL 9.2 database where each account has a schema, like below:

```
My_Database
 |-> Schemas
    |-> AccountA
    |-> AccountB
    |-> AccountC
    |-> AccountD
    |-> AccountE
           .
           .
           .
    |-> AccountZ
    |-> MasterAccount
```

All schemas have a table called `imovel` which has a column called `id`, the structure is:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MasterAccount.imovel_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE MasterAccount.imovel (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('MasterAccount.imovel_id_seq') NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title varchar(80) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE AccountA.imovel (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('MasterAccount.imovel_id_seq') PRIMARY KEY
)
INHERITS (MasterAccount.imovel);

.
.
.

CREATE TABLE AccountZ.imovel (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('MasterAccount.imovel_id_seq') PRIMARY KEY
)
INHERITS (MasterAccount.imovel);
```

Today I have 127 accounts and when I run a `SELECT` in a child table, the response is fast. But when I run the same `SELECT` in the father table, it is slow. I saw the `EXPLAIN` and it seems that PostgreSQL uses each child's index, instead of use only the father index.

Is it possible to improve this behavior?

I need to use `SELECT` in the master table for global searches.

**SELECT in the child table**

[image]

**SELECT in the father table**

[image]

Comment: Lead with your version of Postgres in any such question please. It's particularly relevant with your issue.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, Yes, sir! Done! You help me with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575610/select-retrieve-all-records-from-multiple-schemas-using-postgres) some years ago! The time to improve performance arrived! As you predicted! =D

Comment: [PostgreSQL 9.2 has reached EOL in 2017!](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) Is upgrading to a current version possible? Modern day declarative partitioning >>> old school inheritance. For starters, there is no "father INDEX" in your model. Indexes apply to each table *only*.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, Unfortunately, the current datacenter i use supports only PostgreSQL 9.2. Even `SELECT` running in the "father table" (which as an INDEX) the query planner uses all the "child INDEXES" individually? Any workaround?

Comment: Please don't post execution plans as screen shots, [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) is much easier to read. And whenever possible post the output of  **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** - not just a "simple" explain. To preserve the indention of the plan, paste the plan's text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: Do you want data from all "children" tables when you select from the "father" table? Also, if the data center doesn't support anything less ancient than 9.2, it is time to change data center.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, Yes, it is a global search where I need to find all matches in all acccounts. I am seriously considering to change data center.

Comment: Well, then [my answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62017449/6464308) applies.

Answer (score 1):

> But when I run the same `SELECT` in the father table, it is slow. I saw the `EXPLAIN` and seems that PostgreSQL uses each child's index, instead of use only the father index.

To search in the father table ***only***, use the `ONLY` keyword:

```
 SELECT FROM ONLY MasterAccount.imovel ....
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)

> If `ONLY` is specified before the table name, only that table is scanned.

Comment: When i use `ONLY` in the parent table, no rows are returned. I think it is because inserts are done in child tables.